# How to add antennas to flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I want to add 4 antennas to a block chart (right end). I have tried with
\node (9,0) node[antenna] but it didn't work. My code is below:

```
\documentclass[a4]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Use this if the file is encoded with utf-8
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz} % Create graphics in Latex
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) [draw, rectangle, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=.5cm] (mynode) {$\textit{\textbf{\^{x}}}$};
  \foreach \y in {-0.25, -0.75, 0.25, 0.75}{
    \draw [black, -] (-1,\y) -- ($(mynode.west) +(0,\y)$);
  }

    \node at (2,0) [draw, rectangle, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=.5cm] (mynode) {$\textit{\textbf{(HT})}^{+}$};
  \foreach \y in {-0.25, -0.75, 0.25, 0.75}{
    \draw [black, -] (0.25,\y) -- ($(mynode.west) +(0,\y)$);
  }

  % ... more lines
      \node at (4,0) [draw, rectangle, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=.5cm] (mynode) {$\textit{\textbf{T}}$};
  \foreach \y in {-0.25, -0.75, 0.25, 0.75}{
    \draw [black, -] (2.75,\y) -- ($(mynode.west) +(0,\y)$);
  }

  % ... more lines
      \node at (6,0) [draw, rectangle, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=.5cm] (mynode) {$\textit{\textbf{Y}}$};
  \foreach \y in {-0.25, -0.75, 0.25, 0.75}{
    \draw [black, -] (4.25,\y) -- ($(mynode.west) +(0,\y)$);
  }

      %\node (9,0) node[antenna]
      \node at (8,0) [draw, rectangle, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=.5cm] (mynode) {ADC};

  \foreach \y in {-0.25, -0.75, 0.25, 0.75}{
    \draw [black, -] (6.25,\y) -- ($(mynode.west) +(0,\y)$);
    \draw [black, -] (9.5,\y) -- ($(mynode.east) +(0,\y)$)
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}\\\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\node (9,0) node[antenna]` try with `\node[antenna] at (9,0) {};`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed a little bit your code but with similar results.

First, all blocks are drawn, all with a different name. This way you can later use this name. If you always use `mynode` it's impossible to distinguish among different nodes.

And because we have different names a `foreach` loop can help us to drawn all links between nodes.

Finally, four antennas are drawn at right end of your diagram.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} % Create graphics in Latex
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=5mm}]

  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (0,0) (x) {$\hat{x}$};
  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (2,0) (ht) {$(HT)^+$};
  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (4,0) (t) {$T$};
  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (6,0) (y) {$Y$};
  \node[block, font=\bfseries] at (8,0) (adc) {ADC};
  \foreach \y in {-0.25, -0.75, 0.25, 0.75}{
    \draw [black, -] ([yshift=\y cm]x.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially x)] in {ht,t,y,adc}
        \draw [black, -] ([yshift=\y cm]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
  }

  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=0.75cm]adc.east)--++(0:.5cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=0.25cm]adc.east)--++(0:1.25cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=-0.25cm]adc.east)--++(0:2cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=-0.75cm]adc.east)--++(0:2.75cm) node[antenna] {};

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: `How do I take away the two outermost lines between the (HT)^+ box and the T box?`

If I correctly understand your question, a possible option would be to change `foreach` and take an special case for link between `ht` and `t`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} % Create graphics in Latex
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=5mm}]

  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (0,0) (x) {$\hat{x}$};
  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (2,0) (ht) {$(HT)^+$};
  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (4,0) (t) {$T$};
  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (6,0) (y) {$Y$};
  \node[block, font=\bfseries] at (8,0) (adc) {ADC};
  \foreach \y in {-0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75}{
    \draw ([yshift=\y cm]x.west)--++(180:1cm);
     \foreach \i/\j in {x/ht,t/y,y/adc}
        \draw ([yshift=\y cm]\i.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\j.west);
  }

  \foreach \y in {-0.25, 0.25}{
        \draw ([yshift=\y cm]ht.east)--([yshift=\y cm]t.west);
  }

  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=0.75cm]adc.east)--++(0:.5cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=0.25cm]adc.east)--++(0:1.25cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=-0.25cm]adc.east)--++(0:2cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=-0.75cm]adc.east)--++(0:2.75cm) node[antenna] {};

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I take away the two outermost lines between the (HT)^+ box and the T box? (I am compressing the streams)

Comment: I have added some code. I have made one exact system in parallell, so there is 8 antennas. But I have divided the system in half, and i want to connect the boxes on the left side (CPU side).

Comment: @Bob1990 I've updated the answer for your first comment. About second, I don't understand what it means. But as I think it's a completely different question, would be better that you open a new one.